# Data not showing on Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I am creating an iOS app using swift and parse for the first time. When I create PFObjects, the class names show up online so I believe I am connected to Parse correctly.  Also, when I run

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Items")
var objects = query.findObjects()
var numObjects = objects.count
println(numObjects)
```

I receive confirmation that each time I add something to the database the value printed increases by one.  It has been about six hours since I sent the first data to Parse, and when I run the code above it shows I have over 80 items in the database, but I still see "You don't have any data for this period." on the web site.

My code generates no errors, so I am confused as to why nothing shows up online. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you show where it says "You don't have any data for this period."

Comment: It sounds like you are looking at the analytics dashboard and not the data browser.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 I was looking in the incorrect place.